# Concatenating paths in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $P$ and $Q$ be paths in a graph $G$ so that the end of $P$ is the beginning of $Q$. Let $u$ be the beginning of $P$ and $v$ the end of $Q$. Proof or show a counterexample: if $P$ and $Q$ has different parity then $PQ$ contains an odd path from $u$ to $v$ or an odd cycle.

---

If $P$ and $Q$ has no common vertices then $PQ$ will always be equivalent to $|P|+|Q|\mod 2$.

It is intuitive to me that if there is no odd path then I would find a cycle. However, I don't know how to formally argue this.

Comment: It's easy to see that the subgraph $P\cup Q$ contains an odd path from $u$ to $v$ or an odd cycle. Is that what "$PQ$ contains an odd path from $u$ to $v$ or an odd cycle" means, or do we have to prove something stronger? Exactly what does it mean for a path or cycle to be "contained" in $PQ$?

Comment: @bof A path $P'$ is contained in $PQ$ if $P'$ is a segment of $PQ$.

Comment: This may be a counterexample. Suppose $P=u,a,b,c,d$, a path of length $4$, and $Q=d,e,b,v$, a path of length $3$. There is no odd cycle. There is an odd path from $u$ to $v$, namely the path $P'=u,a,b,v$ but is $P'$ "contained" in $PQ$? According to your comment, "A path $P'$ is contained in $PQ$ if $P'$ is a segment of $PQ$." I don't think $P'$ is a "segment" of $PQ$ but I'm not sure, as you didn't define "segment".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $PQ$ is a path from $u$ to $v$. Then, it must be odd and we are done. Otherwise, let $x$ be the first vertex in $Q$ such that $x \in P\cap Q$. Thus, we have a cycle $C$ in $PQ$ starting and ending in $x$. If $C$ is odd then we are done. Suppose it is not. Then we can define $P'$ as the walk result of the replacement of $C$ by $x$ in $PQ$. Since $C$ is even then $P'$ is odd.

The logic goes on for $P'$. At some moment we will find an odd cycle or no cycle at all, and the last walk will indeed be an odd path.

Comment: Is this correct?